# Pivot table unable to get same output as excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, group-by, pivot-table

I have a dataframe below:

```
Year  Material  Total_amount Customer_code
2019  Table     20           00147
2019  Chair     25           00159
2019  Table     20           00160 
2020  Table     20           00159
2020  Spoon     2            00147     
2020  Fork      2            00147
```

I'm trying to find the customer that keeps coming back

```
cust = (pd.pivot_table(sd_df, 
                         values=['Total Amount','Customer Code'], 
                         index=['Year'], 
                         aggfunc=[np.sum, len]).reset_index()
         )
cust
```

I did this but it returned me this

[image]

Edit: I am trying to get the sum of the total amount and the count of the customer code.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how to obtain either result from the data you have included in your question.  It seems that you have generated both results from far more data than you have included in the question.  What output do you get, both in Pandas and in Excel, from only the data you include in your question?

Comment: hi Luke, i am using the same datasets with equal amounts of data for both. Basically i'm trying to get the same format as excel. With the sum of the total amount and count of all customer code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
print(
    df.groupby('Year').agg(**{
        "Sum_Total_Amount": ('Total_amount', 'sum'),
        "Count_Cust_Code": ('Customer_code', 'nunique'),
    }).reset_index()
)
```

---

```
   Year  Sum_Total_Amount  Count_Cust_Code
0  2019                65                3
1  2020                24                2
```